# sifr 3 doesn't work with update panel

Tags: updatepanel, sifr

i'm using sifr 3 and i'm doing font replacement inside updatepanel.
after postback the flash disappear and i get the pld font instead.
what to do? please help me.
thanks ;)

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I don't know what 'updatepanel' is. An example would help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run the sifr update after your updatepanel is finished..

You can write a script to attach to the PageRequestManager, using an event like add_endRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this snippet in your html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {       
        sIFR.replace(font, { selector: '#content h2' });    
    }
</script>
```

It will run the sIFR replacements each time the page reloads. This is on normal PostBack and Ajax postbacks. Make sure you have included a ScriptManager instance on your page.

note: this question is similar to:
[sIFR not working with prototype AJAX page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435135/sifr-not-working-with-prototype-ajax-page-load).