# sIFR not working with prototype AJAX page load

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, sifr

I have a website with two pages. A and B. When you click on a link in page A, it will uses the Prototype `Ajax.Updater()` to load the link page (page B) into a div on the page (Page A).

When page B loads into page A, the sIFR replacements are not working and the tag inner text is not even showing.

I have tried doing a `sIFR.redraw()` when the page has loaded into the div, with no success.

When i view page B in the browser by itself, it works perfectly.

Is it possible to insert HTML into a DIV tag on a page using AJAX and have the sIFR display properly?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you probably need to re-initialise sIFR within the onComplete callback of Ajax.Updater

Comment: Yes. You need to execute the replacements again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I ended up doing this

```
new Ajax.Updater('content', url, {
  onComplete:function(){
     sIFR.replace(font, {
        selector: '#content h2'
     });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put this snippet in your html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
       sIFR.replace(font, { selector: '#content h2' });
    }
</script>
```

It will run the sIFR replacements each time the page reloads. This is on normal PostBack and Ajax postbacks. Make sure you have included a ScriptManager instance on your page.

Answer (score 0):

**mathijsuitmegen:**
Your solution worked perfectly on an application I'm using where the ScriptManager was already in use.

Infact, The function was simply **slotted into my sifr-config.js** file and worked perfectly meaning my HTML wasn't cluttered.